# Computer Turns Pixelated when It wakes up?

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox

I just started to have a very strange problem. For the last 2 times today when I came back to my computer everything is all pixelated.

It is very strange. I do get the problem some times when I am browsing the internet but never had it this bad

[image]

I went to a random article and as you can see in the square how the text is all funny(sometimes it would be even more more lines). I contently get that while browsing in firefox on a windows 7 64 bit machine.

I even get it when I write this post.

[image]

The weird thing is that I have dual boot with windows 8 64bit and never had that problem once. I also only see it while browsing. I can be in any other software like visual studios and never see it.

I have not tried other browsers to see if it happens.

As I stated in the begging of my post that since today when my computer falls asleep my entire screen basically looks like what I highlighted above in the screenshot.

I tired to screenshot that but when I looked at the screenshots it looks perfectly fine. To fix the problem I had to "lock" my computer what instantly fixed the problem and my screen went back to normal.

Anyone have any idea what is causing this. I first though graphic card but since I don't get this on my windows 8 partition I don't think that would be the problem.

Possible that something is messed up with windows 7?

Comment: which GPU do you use? try to update the driver and look if this fixes it.

Comment: Hmm...Looks like a problem I had on my wife's laptop. Some how (my son did something I am sure) ClearType got unchecked. You may want to inspect that so at least you can wipe it off the list of suspects.

Comment: Is your graphics card an ATI Radeon?

Answer (score 0):

It's a [Firefox issue](https://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+pixelated).

Try to disable hardware acceleration in Firefox ([additional](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/09/hardware-acceleration/), [info](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/Troubleshooting+extensions+and+themes)).

```
Tools > Options > Advanced > General > Browsing: "Use hardware acceleration when available"
```

Try to set the gfx.content.azure.enabled pref to false or if this didn't help disable Direct2D by setting the gfx.direct2d.disabled pref to true on the [about:config page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/about:config) and leave hardware acceleration otherwise enabled.

Comment: Cool. I think that solved on problem but still get the weird problem when my computer falls a sleep.